# Remove remote branch in local env

Tags: git, github, branch

To make question more specific, I'll have example.

I've cloned a project from github. Then I've made some commits and pushed it.
At this moment, if I type `git branch` & `git branch -r` command, I can get list of local branches and remote branches.

`git branch`

[image]

`git branch -r`

[image]

Now, if I want to remove remote branch, `git push origin search -d` will help.

`git push origin search -d`
`git branch -r`

[image]

Great. It works well.

However, If I remove this branch through the github, the problem occurs.

Since my local **does not know** that remote branch is removed, it still retrieves `origin/search` when I type `git branch -r` command. So I tried to use command `git push origin search -d` to remove `origin/search` from my local. However, it threw error like below

[image]
(Sorry for Korean, It means `error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/njh7799/test`)

HaHa. Git cannot remove the remote branch because it does not exists!

Eventually, `origin/search` lives forever in my local when I type `git branch -r`. The question is, how can I delete it?

Comment: Please don't put things like "<Resolved>" in the title; if you accept the dupe, it will be automatically marked as "[Duplicate]"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because "git pull" does not remove remote tracking branches for branches deleted from the remote repo.

SOLUTION:
To remove remote tracking branches for deleted branches, please try the following command:

git remote prune origin

If you just want to list such stale branches (and not remove them), use this:

git remote prune origin --dry-run

Reference here: https://git-scm.com/docs/git-branch